# Disc light comes on when pressing keys in Iceweasel Preferences? Is this malevolent?

Tags: linux, malware, iceweasel

On Linux,I'm using the Iceweasel web browser (it's effectively Firefox), and in Edit/Preferences/General/Startup, when I type a URL into the "Home Page" box, the hard disc light comes on for EVERY press of a key (eg www.google.com). This seems odd (and unnecessary). I've tried entering text in other boxes in Preferences, and the disc light DOESN'T come on.

Do you know why the disc light is coming on, and does it suggest that something sneaky and malevolent is happening? Thanks very much.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Could it be your swap?

Check out iostat and iotop to track down what's going on. Could alternatively be a question for the iceweasel community, point them here for more feedback.